# GeoCoding and setting global variables iOS

Tags: ios, geocoding

I have two global NSString variables called myLocality and myCountry...

I have set GeoCode up as below:

```
    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    finishedGettingLocation = false;
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 200.0f){
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        __block NSString *locality;
        __block NSString *country;
        [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks) {
                locality = placemark.locality;
                country = placemark.ISOcountryCode;
            }
        }];
        do {

        } while ([geoCoder isGeocoding]);

        myLocality = locality;
        myCountry = country;

        finishedGettingLocation = true;        
    }    
}
```

And my background thread is as follows:

```
- (void) doWork
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{                   

        finishedGettingLocation = false;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            [locationManager setDelegate:self];

            [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        });

        int counter = 0;
        do {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.1];
            counter ++;
            if (counter % 200 == 0){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    Toast *oToast = [Toast toastWithMessage:@"Gps pin-pointing works faster if you are outside"];
                    [oToast showOnView:self.view];
                });
                counter = 0;
            }

        } while (!finishedGettingLocation);

      NSLog(@"%@", myCountry); // this is where I am trying to print
      NSLog(@"%@", myLocality); // this is where I am trying to print

    });
}
```

(Yeah, I know it's pretty sloppy code, but, meh.. xD)

Now, what I can't figure out is why these are returning null when I log them in my code elsewhere.
However, when I put log in the above `for`, i.e `NSLog(@"%@", placemark.locality)` I get the correct value, or at least I get a value.

How can I set the global variables from the `placemark`?

Comment: Where are you trying to print out their values? The doWork method? I would try stepping through both methods to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out my problem. Turns out, I was accessing the variables too early. I simply changed the `do while` loop's condition to `myCountry == null` and it worked =]. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Where are these variables declared?

If you make `myLocality` and `myCountry` static in your class that is doing the geocoding, then other classes can access them once they are set.

Another way to do it would be to create a `@protocol` and have the class that wants the results of the geocoding to receive a callback once it's done.

Comment: Well, I have declared the variables in the @interface part of my `.m` file. Before I call the GeoCode, I call locationManager, I have put the GeoCode code in `- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {` This void method, along with the GeoCode and variables are all in the same file. I am trying to access the `myLocality` and `myCountry` in the same `.m` file. If that makes sense?

Comment: So maybe you are accessing them too early? Can you post the full code snippet?

Comment: Well, I don't think so, I have everything in a background thread. Besides the `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` which then fires off that above void method, and then calls the GeoCode part. But I have a `do loop` "waiting" until the GeoCoder has finished working. PS: I'll update my original post...

Comment: Ok, I found out my problem. Turns out, I was accessing the variables too early. I simply changed the `do while` loop's condition to `myCountry == null` and it worked =]. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Create locality and country properties in AppDelegate and access them where ever you want.

```
// Set values
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.locality = @"Some Area";
appDelegate.country = @"Some Country";


// Get values
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString *myLocality = appDelegate.locality;
NSString *myCountry = appDelegate.country;
```

You can also create a dedicated singleton class and use it instead of using app delegate.